# How to extract loadings from PCA - while conserving variable loading/variable names

Tags: r

I have performed a sucessfull PCA, and now I wish to extract the loadings.

***I ran the PCA***

```
    #Run PCA and plot results
pca <- prcomp(dataset_numeric[c(1:8, 10:11, 13:18),c(1:ncol(data_tsc))], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
summary(pca)
```

**Attempts to extract loadings**

```
loading_PC <- pca$rotation[,2] %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE)
```

*Which returned this*

[image]

I afterwards tried to organize this into a data frame using the following code:

```
loading_PC <- pca$rotation[,2]  %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% as.data.frame(row.names = TRUE)
```

*Which returned*

[image]

As you can see, all the gene names (variable, loadings names) are missing, so I was wondering if there is any way that I can perserve them. Thank you in advance.

**Changes**
I added dput for Loading_PC as asked:

```
    c(A1CF = -0.146219143927011, AACS = -0.231151131955, AATK = -0.485220551393282, 
ABCA1 = -0.222934271967757, ABCA5 = 0.282376223269048, ABCA7 = 0.0779960358397119, 
ABCB9 = -0.389273153643306, ABCC4 = -0.611693335877105, ABCC5 = 0.129182251850867, 
ABCD2 = 0.108813374460373)
```

Comment: maybe library `broom` can help. `library(broom); tidy(pca, "rotation")` should return a tibble of loadings and variable names

Comment: Hey, this didnt work. Error: unexpected symbol in:
"tidy(pca, "rotation". I also tried some other variants, such as: tidy(pca, pca$rotation). The still problem still arise :)

Comment: Please make this a reproducibel example, by adding data with `dput`.  Otherwise hard to diagnose.  For comparison the following reprex works as expected: `pca <- prcomp(USArrests); loading_PC <- pca$rotation[,2] %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE); data.frame(loading_PC)`

Comment: @NewbieCoder also look into the [documentation of prcomp tidiers](https://broom.tidyverse.org/reference/prcomp_tidiers.html).

Comment: Hey, I added dput as you requested. Its in the main question

Comment: Using your `dput` data, simply `data.frame(loading_PC)` works as expected with row names

Comment: Hey this worked fantastic! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hey,  I got a new problem again. This worked great when I set:
pca <- prcomp(dataset_numeric[c(1:8, 10:11, 13:18),c(1:10)], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
summary(pca),
however when I set 
pca <- prcomp(dataset_numeric[c(1:8, 10:11, 13:18),c(1:ncol(dataset_numeric))], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)

The same problem arised as before.

I am working with confidential data, RNA expression with over 4600 variables, and I can post all the results from dput here on this website. If you understand :)

Comment: @NewbieCoder You should mark this question as solved and ask a new question with your new problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names are missing because you pass an atomic vector to sort(), and in return, it gives you an atomic vector. Reorder the hole matrix/df with order, and then subset with drop = FALSE:

```
> rm(list = ls())
> 
> data(iris)
> 
> iris.pca <- prcomp(iris[colnames(iris) != "Species"], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
> iris.weights <- data.frame(iris.pca$rotation)
> 
> # Names are lost
> NoNames <- sort(iris.weights[, 2], decreasing = TRUE)
> NoNames
[1] -0.02449161 -0.06694199 -0.37741762 -0.92329566
> 
> # Names are preserve
> WithNames <- iris.weights[order(iris.weights[, 2], decreasing = TRUE),][, 2, drop = FALSE]
> WithNames
                     PC2
Petal.Length -0.02449161
Petal.Width  -0.06694199
Sepal.Length -0.37741762
Sepal.Width  -0.92329566
>
```

Here is with the last dput():

```
> # With dput
> 
> df <- data.frame(c(A1CF = -0.146219143927011, AACS = -0.231151131955, AATK = -0.485220551393282,
+         ABCA1 = -0.222934271967757, ABCA5 = 0.282376223269048, ABCA7 = 0.0779960358397119,
+         ABCB9 = -0.389273153643306, ABCC4 = -0.611693335877105, ABCC5 = 0.129182251850867,
+         ABCD2 = 0.108813374460373))
> 
> colnames(df) <- "weights"
> 
> sort(df$weights, decreasing = TRUE)
 [1]  0.28237622  0.12918225  0.10881337  0.07799604 -0.14621914 -0.22293427 -0.23115113
 [8] -0.38927315 -0.48522055 -0.61169334
> 
> df[order(df$weights, decreasing = TRUE),,drop = FALSE]
          weights
ABCA5  0.28237622
ABCC5  0.12918225
ABCD2  0.10881337
ABCA7  0.07799604
A1CF  -0.14621914
ABCA1 -0.22293427
AACS  -0.23115113
ABCB9 -0.38927315
AATK  -0.48522055
ABCC4 -0.61169334
>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not see anywhere that OP used `order`

Comment: @dww Thanks for picking that. I have modify it.

Comment: @NewbieCoder Please see with last added dput.

Comment: Hey, I tried this. It did work, and then it did not work.
This worked great when I set: pca <- prcomp(dataset_numeric[c(1:8, 10:11, 13:18),c(1:10)], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE) summary(pca), however when I set pca <- prcomp(dataset_numeric[c(1:8, 10:11, 13:18),c(1:ncol(dataset_numeric))], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE) The same problem arised as before. I am working with confidential data, RNA expression with over 4600 variables, and I can post all the results from dput here on this website. If you understand

Comment: @NewbieCoder, the only difference between the two are the subset of your data frame. Indeed, if it has 10 columns, it has to come to the same result. The summary of the PCA gives you the explained variance, not the weights of the linear transformation.